# WCF with GZipCompression

Tags: wcf, gzip

I am passing the data to front end via WCF and binding the data using jQuery binding. From WCF I need to pass large amount of data,so it takes so much time to load. By going through other posts I come to know that GZip could be used for this. But I am not aware of the process. Please do help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways of compressing large output in WCF:

1. Configure IIS to use compression.  First, the compression feature has to be included in your server's install (not the default). Second, you can use IIS manager, to find the "compression" feature and enable it, per app.  MSDN has some good directions to describe each step.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003(v=ws.10).aspx
2. Configure WCF to use Mtom compression. This is set in your web.config, in the section `<bindings><wsHttpBinding><binding messageEncoding="Mtom" ...`.  This SO, article has some very good examples, with explanations, etc.  [Streaming with WCF and MTOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525402/streaming-with-wcf-and-mtom)